# scipy linprog output does not match docs

Tags: python, scipy

I tried reproducing the `scipy.optimize.linprog` example code, pasted below from the docs:

```
>>> c = [-1, 4]
>>> A = [[-3, 1], [1, 2]]
>>> b = [6, 4]
>>> x0_bounds = (None, None)
>>> x1_bounds = (-3, None)
>>> res = linprog(c, A_ub=A, b_ub=b, bounds=(x0_bounds, x1_bounds),
...               options={"disp": True})
>>> print(res)
Optimization terminated successfully.
     Current function value: -11.428571
     Iterations: 2
status: 0
success: True
fun: -11.428571428571429
x: array([-1.14285714,  2.57142857])
message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
nit: 2
```

However, I actually get the following output when I run this:

```
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: -22.000000  
         Iterations: 1
     fun: -22.0
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nit: 1
   slack: array([ 39.,   0.])
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([ 10.,  -3.])
```

The solution on my computer seems correct, so I am wondering why the divergence.

Comment: So you just copied the command and put into a script, then ran it? Does it consistently return the same output for each way?

Comment: I checked the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html), and the output listed there matches the output you say you got, not the output you say is in the docs. What docs are you looking at?

Comment: Going back to an [older version of the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html) shows the output you say is in the docs. This is probably a documentation error that got fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a documentation error that [got fixed](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/4438). (It needs a bit more fixing, because they forgot to update the value in the note under the code example.)

Comment: Thanks!  much obliged